# Gmapping not marking inf values as free space

Tags: ros, gazebo, navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Im working with gmapping and a simulated robot in gazebo under ROS Kinetic.The problem that I have is that gmapping doesn't draw the space under the rays that didn't hit anything as free space.

The first image shows the map displayed in rviz and the second one the simulation environment.

[image: rviz]

[image: gazebo]

My values for the ranges are:

maxRange = 11.0

maxURange = 9.0

gazeboLaserRange = 10.0

I am using the libgazebo_ros_gpu_laser.so for the laser in gazebo.

Any idea why this happens?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258149/gmapping-not-marking-inf-values-as-free-space/) by [juanlu](https://answers.ros.org/users/29661/juanlu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 189 on 2017-03-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is exactly what I expect from gmapping or any other slam algorithm. Having no obstacle in the range of laser means no sensor readings and therefore no information to fill the map. But don't worry, as soon as you start to move around your slam algorithm starts to fill in the map for you.

---

Originally posted by [mohsen1989m](https://answers.ros.org/users/22803/mohsen1989m/) with karma: 397 on 2017-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [juanlu](https://answers.ros.org/users/29661/juanlu/) on 2017-04-05**:
I understand that, and I am aware of the fact that the map fills when I move around. My question is why does this happen? Why not fill the space until maxRange of the laser with free space?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-06-15**:
Because you don't know if it's an inf response due to not seeing something or the laser being dazzled or otherwise interfered with.